# AWS Lambda Timeouts randomly

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda

We have created a NodeJS based Lambda function named - execInspector which gets triggered everyday once. This function is created based on AWS Lambda blueprint --> "inspector-scheduled-run" in NodeJS.

The problem we see is the scheduled job fails randomly one day or the other. We are getting only the below logs from the cloudwatch log stream.

In a week, it randomly runs =~ 4/5 times & fails remaining days. Based on the log, it consumes only very little amount of memory/time for its execution but not sure why it fails randomly. It also retries itself 3 times before getting killed.

From the below log we could also find that the job only takes 35 MB avg. & takes only 60 sec to complete on an avg. We tried modifying the NodeJS run time, increasing memory, timeouts well beyond this limit but nothing worked out.

Can you please help with some alternate approaches to handle these failures automatically & if anyone has insights on why its happening?

Additional Inputs:
We have already given 5 mins of maximum timeout also, but it fails saying "timed out after 300 secs.".

What i mean here is the task of just triggering the inspector takes only less than 30 secs on avg. Since, its a PaaS based solution, I cannot expect always this to be completed within 30 secs. But 60 secs should be more than enough for this to handle a job which it was able to complete within 30 secs.

Sample CloudWatch Successful log:

18:01:00
START RequestId: 12eb468a-4174-11e7-be7b-6d0faaa584aa Version: $LATEST
18:01:03
2017-05-25T18:01:02.935Z 12eb468a-4174-11e7-be7b-6d0faaa584aa { assessmentRunArn: 'arn:aws:inspector:us-east-1:102461617910:target/0-Ly60lmEP/template/0-POpZxSLA/run/0-MMx30fLl' }
2017-05-25T18:01:02.935Z 12eb468a-4174-11e7-be7b-6d0faaa584aa { assessmentRunArn: 'arn:aws:inspector:us-east-1:102461617910:target/0-Ly60lmEP/template/0-POpZxSLA/run/0-MMx30fLl' }
18:01:03
END RequestId: 12eb468a-4174-11e7-be7b-6d0faaa584aa
END RequestId: 12eb468a-4174-11e7-be7b-6d0faaa584aa
18:01:03
REPORT RequestId: 12eb468a-4174-11e7-be7b-6d0faaa584aa Duration: 2346.37 ms Billed Duration: 2400 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 33 MB
REPORT RequestId: 12eb468a-4174-11e7-be7b-6d0faaa584aa Duration: 2346.37 ms Billed Duration: 2400 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 33 MB

***Cloudwatch log:***

Similar log below is repeated 3 times which seems to be a retry attempt

*06:32:52
START RequestId: 80190395-404a-11e7-845d-1f88a00ed4f3 Version: $LATEST
06:32:56
2017-05-24T06:32:55.942Z 80190395-404a-11e7-845d-1f88a00ed4f3 Execution Started...
06:33:52
END RequestId: 80190395-404a-11e7-845d-1f88a00ed4f3
06:33:52
REPORT RequestId: 80190395-404a-11e7-845d-1f88a00ed4f3 Duration: 60000.88 ms Billed Duration: 60000 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 32 MB
06:33:52
2017-05-24T06:33:52.437Z 80190395-404a-11e7-845d-1f88a00ed4f3 Task timed out after 60.00 seconds
2017-05-24T06:33:52.437Z 80190395-404a-11e7-845d-1f88a00ed4f3 Task timed out after 60.00 seconds*

**Lambda code:**

```
'use strict';

/**
 * A blueprint to schedule a recurring assessment run for an Amazon Inspector assessment template.
 *
 * This blueprint assumes that you've already done the following:
 * 1. onboarded with the Amazon Inspector service https://aws.amazon.com/inspector
 * 2. created an assessment target - what hosts you want to assess
 * 3. created an assessment template - how you want to assess your target
 *
 * Then, all you need to do to use this blueprint is to define an environment variable in the Lambda console called
 * `assessmentTemplateArn` and provide the template arn you want to run on a schedule.
 */

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const inspector = new AWS.Inspector();

const params = {
    assessmentTemplateArn: process.env.assessmentTemplateArn,
};

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    try {
        // Inspector.StartAssessmentRun response will look something like:
        // {"assessmentRunArn":"arn:aws:inspector:us-west-2:123456789012:target/0-wJ0KWygn/template/0-jRPJqnQh/run/0-Ga1lDjhP"
        inspector.startAssessmentRun(params, (error, data) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error, error.stack);
                return callback(error);
            }

            console.log(data);
            return callback(null, data);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Caught Error: ', error);
        callback(error);
    }
};
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

The log says your request is timing out after 60 seconds. You can set it as high as 5 minutes according to this https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-lambda-update-python-vpc-increased-function-duration-scheduling-and-more/ If your task takes about 60 seconds and the timeout is 60 secs then maybe some are timing out. Thats what the log suggests to me. Otherwise, post some code from the function

Comment: pls refer above my added details